# how to create the sql sentence to obtain the following result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following table in my data base

The table name is "product_question"

```
product_question_id int(11) No       
product_id  int(11) No       
user_name   varchar(100)    No       
user_email  varchar(200)    No       
envipor varchar(100)    No       
company_name    varchar(100)    No       
product_name    varchar(100)    No       
question    text    No       
product_image   varchar(500)    No       
date    timestamp   No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

and i have the following sql statement

the sentenced SQL in my .php page is that is

```
SELECT*
FROM product_question
WHERE company_name = $_SESSION['company_name']
```

but I want the results on my .php page, into a simple statement shown in this way

```
product: xbox 360
question: what is the price? - user_name: brian

product: ps3
question: has availability? - user_name: carlos

product: xbox 360
question: has games? - michael

product: ps3
question: what is the price? - user_name: luke

product:  smartphone
question : brings android? - selena

product: xbox 360
question: how many games? - user_name: daniel
```

I want the outcome of the sentence is displayed in this way

**product: xbox 360**

```
question: what is the price? - user_name: brian
question: has games? - michael
question: how many games? - user_name: daniel
```

**product: ps3**

```
question: has availability? - user_name: carlos
question: what is the price? - user_name: luke
```

**product:  smartphone**

```
question : brings android? - selena
```

but, I do not know to create the sql sentence to obtain the desired result.

Comment: If you just escapse and quote your sql argument you should be okay, `WHERE company_name = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SESSION['company_name']).
"'"`, or use prepared statements.

Comment: do not need that, I just want to see the sentence of the form as in the example

Comment: you have to escape and quote the where argument or the query will be invalid. if you want the results to contain the data as you have specified you just have to use the sql concatenate function `CONCATENATE('question: ', question, ' - ', user_name)`

Comment: well, write to me the answer with the function you're giving to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments the method to get your results from the database in the format that you require you require you would issue a query that looked like this. This is assuming  you are using the procedural style of mysqli.

```
$sql = "select CONCATENATE('question: ', question, ' - ', user_name) as questionText ".
       "from product_question ".
       "WHERE company_name = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnection, $_SESSION['company_name'])."'";
```